# If $rank(S) \leq nullity(T)$ then is $rank(S^*) \geq nullity(T^*)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, alternative-proof, matrix-rank, adjoint-operators

Here $T:V \rightarrow W$ and $S:W \rightarrow V$, where V and W are finite dimensional inner-product spaces over the same field. It's also given that $TS=0$.

The question is to prove that $rank(S^*) \geq nullity(T^*)$.

My attempt: Using the fact that $TS=0$, I derived that $rank(S) \leq nullity(T)$. Does the inequality asked automatically follow from this? If not, please give alternate ways to prove the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that $\operatorname{Rank}(S) \leq \operatorname{Nullity}(T)$ implies that $\operatorname{Rank}(S^*) \geq \operatorname{Nullity}(T^*)$. For a counterexample, let $V = W$ be vector spaces of positive dimension and let $S = T = 0$. Then $\operatorname{Rank}(S) = 0$ and $\operatorname{Nullity}(T) = \operatorname{dim}(V) > 0$, but $S^* = T^* = 0$, so also $\operatorname{Rank}(S^*) = 0 < \operatorname{dim}(V) = \operatorname{Nullity}(T^*)$.

The same counterexample actually shows that it cannot follow from $TS = 0$ that $\operatorname{Rank}(S^*) \geq \operatorname{Nullity}(T^*)$, so it appears that the question you are trying to prove is incorrect.

Something that you can prove though is that $\operatorname{Nullity}(S^*) \geq \operatorname{Rank}(T^*)$. This follows from what you did in your attempt by observing that $S^*T^* = (TS)^* = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Bastiaan, really appreciate it. I'll give you the full question that was asked, and can you tell me if it's still incorrect? Would be really helpful if you could do that.

Comment: I think the second statement is incorrect. Consider again the above counterexample, then $T^* = S^* = 0$ so $\operatorname{rank}(S^*) + \operatorname{rank}(T^*) = 0 < \operatorname{dim}(W)$.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for clearing this up.